# Send some requests in Apache jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on Apache Jmeter. I am going to simulate DOS attack with this software, so I need a script for benign client and script for malicious client. benign client send a request every second and malicious client send 10 request per second. How should I do it?

Comment: What types of requests are you talking about? Did you read the [getting started guide for JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)? Your question is overly broad and does not show you've put in effort. Can you please update the question with what you've tried so far and what challenge you're facing?

Comment: You can add two separate thread-groups to your test plan with different request rates to achieve what you're asking for in JMeter

Comment: one of the thread group for benign client, the other for malicious client, isnt it?

Comment: I just want to simulate DOS attack, I think HTTP Request can do it. cant it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler will be quite enough to simulate your scenario.

1. Make sure that you provide enough threads on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Amount of request per second can be precisely controlled by [Constant Throughput](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) Timer

Comment: why constant throghput?

Comment: Cause it is the only out-of-box way to precisely set request execution rate. I believe that it should be enough to implement your test scenario. There is an extended version - [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available via JMeter Plugins.

Comment: So I should have two separate HTTP Request. one of them for benign client which send a request every second, the other one for malicious client which send 10 request every second. Is it enough?

Comment: I would rather go for 2 separate thread groups having 1 request each

Comment: After that I should produce a graph with two factors (response time and experiment time) . how should I define my factors?

Comment: After that I should produce a graph with two factors (response time and experiment time) . how should I define my factors?